# .on load in jquery not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a simple tampermonkey script which will fetch some additional info for items in shop.
I decided to use .each() on document load and it works fine.

Now when I see that the page can change (some items can be removed, some can be added), the newly created items don't contain the additional information...

```
$(document).on("load",".item",function( event ) {
    $(this).html($(this).html() + "OK");
});
```

before it was:

```
$(".item").each(function( event ) {
    $(this).html($(this).html() + "OK");
});
```

and it worked fine.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Because when you add new items, load does not fire....

Comment: Can you show HTML and or make a fiddle? And why use on load with jquery? Just put the working code inside of $(function(){your code});

Comment: I guess you've got a function to add items, I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but can't you have your code running on this function?

Comment: any issues with my code here?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need mutation observers here, you will need a combo of the code below:

This one is for on load

```
$(document).ready(function( event ) {
   $(".item").each(function( event ) {
    $(this).html($(this).html() + "OK");
    });
});
```

and this one will catch all the changes on the dom on ".item"

```
var target = $( ".item" );
// Create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function( mutations ) {
   mutations.forEach(function( mutation ) {
   var newNodes = mutation.addedNodes; // DOM NodeList
if( newNodes !== null ) { // If there are new nodes added

    //alert('some thing has been changed');
      $(".item").each(function( event ) {
          $(this).html($(this).html() + "OK");
      });

      }
   });    
});

// Configuration of the observer:
var config = { 
attributes: true, 
childList: true, 
characterData: true 
};

// Pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
// Later, you can stop observing
//observer.disconnect();
```

Answer (score 0):

With jquery it is as simple as `$(function(){ your code here })` to create functions that will run after page load. This should do it :

```
$(function(){
  $(".item").each(function( event ) {
    $(this).html($(this).html() + "OK");
  });
});
```

You could also simplify your jQuery a bit this way :

```
$(function(){
  $(".item").append('OK');
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/jh1bvux2/

Comment: It wont execute for future elements

Comment: Ah sorry I did not read properly. What I would see in that case is that the function adding the new elements (an ajax call or something like that) should handle that. It could fire an event or directly call the function doing what you need to be done. The only solution left is an observer like sanki suggested. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FMutationObserver#Browser_compatibility

Comment: You could also use a `setInterval` but it is very dirty in that case.

Comment: Set Interval - dirty and bad complexity.
I'm writing tampermonkey script - can't access adding functions...